# Paypal integration with Magento 2.1

Tags: magento, paypal

I am trying to integrate Paypal with Magento 2.1. However, I get the following error message:

> Error Processing Payment
>
> Error Message" This transaction can't be processed. Please pay with
>   another card.

I have set up Paypal as a payment method: Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment Methods

The "Merchant Country" is "United Kingdom".

I have set up an "API Signature".

Still the same error. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the payment was declined due to the credit card issue. Please try with a new credit card or paypal account to test your payment.
To get the details on the previous card decline, please contact [PayPal customer service](http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_contact-phone)